# How to perform Denormalization in Hbase?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, rdbms, nosql

We are trying to **migrate our existing RDBMS(Sql Database) system to hadoop**. We are **planning to use hbase** for the same. But we are not getting how to denormalize sql data to store it in hbase column format.

Is it possible? If yes then what would be the best approach for that?

Which hbase version is required for this?

Any suggestions.

Comment: Here's a link that might be helpful: https://www.mapr.com/blog/guidelines-hbase-schema-design

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the need to denormalize the data, another option is to use one of several SQL engines on top of HBase, such as [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) or [Splice Machine](http://community.splicemachine.com/community/code-repository/). Disclaimer, I work for Splice Machine.